# Flames Of War tank movement

Tags: flames-of-war

I'm new to this game and gaming in general. I have general questions about tank movement.

At the end of a tank's turn is it allowed to turn and face any direction it wants (to keep front armor toward enemy)? If not, how do you complete your movement before next player's turn?